# Dropbox Core API 500 Internal Server Error on a remote server only -- works fine locally

Tags: ruby, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am using the Ruby SDK to interface with the Dropbox Core API. Locally, I am having no issues using the API in any way. On my AWS server, however, the DB API returns a 500 internal server error every time. This is not a sporadic issue, as it has occurred consistently, across on multiple days.

For reference, here is some sample code which works locally, but results in a 500 error on my EC2 instance:

```
session = DropboxSession.new(<app key>, <app secret>)

session.set_access_token(<access token>, <access token secret>)

client = DropboxClient.new(session, 'dropbox')

client.account_info
```

**The error I'm getting:**

```
DropboxError: Dropbox Server Error: #<Net::HTTPInternalServerError:0x000000067f9cd8> - {"error": "Internal Server Error"}
```

Anyone see this before / have any insight into what is going on here? Would really appreciate some help on this :)

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205069189-Getting-500-Internal-Server-Error-on-a-remote-server-only-works-fine-locally- ]